# Apply chosen to jtable multi select dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jquery-jtable

I'm wondering how to apply `chosen` to multi-select drop-down in `jtable`. I've tried adding `chosen-select` as `class` but its not working. I've tried `ajaxComplete` also to check whether it might not be working because of `ajax completion` but it didn't help.

Here's my code:

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
 }); //post ajax
```

Also I've tried with `data-rel="chosen"` to in `jquery.jtable.js`, but it didn't help either. The multi-select list is coming but the problem is I have to show over 3500 locations in the list and it would become difficult to scroll and search locations, so that's why I want to use `chosen` so that I can search in the text box which it suggests and one can easily select, and delete locations. I've tried posting images but reputation prevented me from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. Need to do slight modification in jquery.jtable.js

Need to add two below lines before return statement inside `_createDropDownListMultiForField` function

```
var $select_option = $('<script>  $(".chosen-select").chosen();  $(document).ajaxComplete(function () { $(".chosen-select").chosen();});</script> ');
$containerDiv.append($select_option);
return $containerDiv;
```